# Adding error bars to a scatter chart in a Google spreadsheet

Tags: charts, google-apps-script

I'm a physics teacher trying to use Google Sheets to do collaborative work in the lab. I already managed to add trend lines to a scatter chart through a google apps script. What I'd like to do now is add some custom error bars, specifying a different value for each data point. According to [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/intervals), it seems to be possible. However, I'm at a loss when it comes to defining column roles programmatically and integrating them in the chart.

Here is how I create a basic chart:

```js
function scatterMe() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var chart = sheet.newChart().asScatterChart()
       .addRange(sheet.getRange("C5:D13"))
       .setPosition(2, 10, 0, 0)
       .setOption('series', {0: {pointSize: 2, color: 'black'}})
       .build();
    sheet.insertChart(chart);
};
```

I created 2 columns containing the intervals for the errors bars, let's say `G5:H13`. How could I use this range to create errors bars (`style: 'bars'`) in my chart?

Thanks a lot!